# Theme is not switched when overriding DoGetThemeItem

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms, pipelines, development

I am implementing this [article](https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/09/14/switch-sxa-themes-based-on-cookie-value/) so I can switch themes based on the a cookie or query string. My code is as follows.

```
protected override Item DoGetThemeItem(Item item, DeviceItem device)
    {
        Item themeItem = base.DoGetThemeItem(item, device);
        Item newThemeItem;
        string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query);

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ThemeCookie"] != null)
        {
            string themeValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ThemeCookie"].Value;

            if (themeValue == "something")
            {
                newThemeItem = global::Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(Foundation.Sitecore.Constants.MyThemeID));                    
            }else
            {
                newThemeItem = themeItem;
            }
            return newThemeItem;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString["theme"]))
        {
            string themeValue = queryString["theme"];

            if (themeValue == "something")
            {
                newThemeItem = global::Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(Foundation.Sitecore.Constants.MyThemeID));
            }
            else
            {
                newThemeItem = themeItem; 
            }
            return newThemeItem;
        }          
        else
        {
            return themeItem; 
        }
    }

    private void SetThemeCookie(string themeName)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ThemeCookie", themeName);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        cookie.SameSite = System.Web.SameSiteMode.None;
        cookie.Path = "/";
        cookie.Domain = "dev.local";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

The problem it only switches themes after I run "sxa rebuild All". Any idea why?

Comment: Most probably you haven't replaced original `ThemeContext` with your custom one - the article mentions configuration change which does that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few suggestions as mentioned below, could you please try them if not done?

1. You can locate the `App_Config/Sitecore/Mvc/Sitecore.Mvc.config` file, there is a setting called `Mvc.UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer`, change its default value `false` to `true`.
2. As per the blog post, please ensure this custom class `[CustomAssetLinksGenerator]` is also added to your implementation which has a method `GenerateAssetLinks`.
   You can take this class from this.
   Git Repo  https://github.com/jitendrachilate/ThemeSwitcher.git
   https://github.com/jitendrachilate/ThemeSwitcher/blob/master/Pipeline/CustomThemingContext.cs

Also, please refer to the below git link which has `CustomSxaLayout.cshtml` file. Please check line no 10 wherein the `CustomThemingContext.cs` file is referred to.
Please ensure the same in your implementation.

https://github.com/jitendrachilate/ThemeSwitcher/blob/master/Views/SxaLayout/CustomSxaLayout.cshtml

Blog Post: https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/09/14/switch-sxa-themes-based-on-cookie-value/

Please let me know if you still have any queries. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it was number (2). I forgot to implement CustomAssetLinkGenerator.